# Validation stopped working on use of formmethod.post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to post external URL for eg. (www.msn.com) on press of submit button.But when I do that none of my valdation works...it simply make an entry without any data in my external url
2. Also its not going to controller when i press submit button.
I don't know if I am doing anything wrong...

Here is my code for View:

```
@model n.Models.PopupDemoModel 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>




 @using (Html.BeginForm("Demo","Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @action = "https://www.msn.com?encoding=UTF-8/post" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>   

        <input type=hidden name="oid" value="">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value = "test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1 />
<input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value = "a@test.com" />

    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name, new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.phone, new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone)
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company, new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company)
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_2 sub-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_2 submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="demo-submit-button"/><br />
        @ViewData["DemoMessage"]
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Here is my model:

```
 public class PopupDemoModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Email]
        [DisplayName("Email address")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Phone number")]
        public string phone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Contact name")]
        public string first_name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Company name")]
        public string company { get; set; }


        public string MessageSent
        {
            get { return "We'll contact you shortly."; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: is there any way atleast to validate the page before it get submit...other than clientvalidation

Answer (score 1):

It's doing exactly what you told it to.

The HTML `<form>` tag sends a POST request to the URL in the `action` attribute.

`Html.BeginForm()` creates a `<form>` tag with an `action` attribute that points to your controller.

When you set the `action` attribute explicitly, you replace the value from MVC and make it go directly to that URL.

Comment: is there any way atleast to validate the page before it get submit...other than clientvalidation

Comment: @user207888: No.  You cannot execute server-side code without POSTing to your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with your data on server side before posting to another website, remove the `action` attribute so you will be posting to the same URL as at the beggining. In the action that is handling the `POST` from this form and doing the validation prepare your data. When you're ready, use [WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) to send this data to another website using `POST` method.

Comment: thanks I did it with  using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var values = new NameValueCollection 
                { {"phone", demoModel.phone },
                    {"company", demoModel.company},
                    {"lead_source","Demo Request"}

                };
                        // send values for processing to the external url
                var result = client.UploadValues("https://test/post");

Comment: @user207888 I'm glad you achieved what you wanted to do. If my answer helped but you didn't use my solution, you can vote up my answer and then [post your own answer with your solution and then accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).